# How to create dynamic filter based on dynamic parameters?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm having a hard time coming up with a solution to generate necessary logic and output based on dynamic filtering. I'm working on a script in Google Apps Script and I'm using `doGet()` to act like a webhook. Parameters are sent to this webhook and then based on the provided parameters, data is filtered from a spreadsheet. This means that I have to create my own filter based on the params sent. Initially, I started trying to create the conditions manually. However, I realized that the combination of optional parameters is over 250 and that would take me forever! The flow goes like this:

These are all of the params that are accepted: `(exch,base,dir,durmin,durmax,drawmin,drawmax,askmin,askmax,excessmin,excessmax,maxdcalvl,maxdcapercent,numcalls)`

Of these, there are 6 required params:
`(exch,base,dir,durmax,drawmax,maxdcalvl)`

These are optional:
`(durmin,drawmin,askmin,askmax,excessmin,excessmax,maxdcapercent,numcalls)`

The logic required for each param follows this pattern:
`exch == exchange && base == baseC && dir == direction`

`duration >= durmin && duration <= durmax`
`drawdown <= drawmin && drawdown >= drawmax`

The important things to note here are these params basically just help locate the data on the sheet `exch == exchange && base == baseC && dir == direction` and are essentially just returned. There are no other comparisons made with these.

The other params follow this pattern:
`duration >= durmin && duration <= durmax`
`drawdown <= drawmin && drawdown >= drawmax`
Where the first variable is the data from the for loop that needs to be filtered and the min/max variables are the min and max params sent by the user that are used to actually filter the data like such `askSpread (for loop data) >= askmin (user input) && askSpread (for loop data) <= askmax (user input)`. Again each of these params are optional so the user may only end up sending `askmin` and thus I would only need `askSpread >= askmin` instead of `askSpread (for loop data) >= askmin (user input) && askSpread (for loop data) <= askmax (user input)` or vice versa with the max.

So a simplified explanation - if the param either required or optional does not have both min/max then I am simply just making sure the data being called is coming from the right location on the sheet AKA: `exch == binance && base == btc && dir == long`

Anything with a min/max I'm using those to create the min and max criteria
`duration >= durmin && duration <= durmax` - Filter the data where data is >= durmin (say 1) and the data is <= durmax (say 4)

This is a snippet from my code that is returning the correct values. However, this method requires me to key in all 250+ combinations of params based on if statements. I'm thinking `.filter()` is a better solution. But I am not familiar with how to use it correctly. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am completely stumped at the moment. PS. If you are not familiar with Google Apps Script, I am limited in certain functionalities of Javascript.

> Apps Script is a scripting language for light-weight application development >in the G Suite platform. It is based on JavaScript 1.6 with some portions of >1.7 and 1.8 and provides subset of ECMAScript 5 API,[2] however instead of >running on the client, it gets executed in the Google Cloud. According to >Google, Apps Script "provides easy ways to automate tasks across Google >products and third party services."[3] Apps Script is also the tool that >powers the add-ons for Google Docs, Sheets and Slides.[4]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Apps_Script

```
function test() {
  //  exch,base,dir,durmin,durmax,drawmin,drawmax,askmin,askmax,excessmin,excessmax
  var d = data('binance','bnb','long',0.5,3,-1,-3,0,0,5,0);
  Logger.log(d)

}

function data(exch,base,dir,durmin,durmax,drawmin,drawmax,askmin,askmax,excessmin,excessmax){
  var exch = exch.toLowerCase();
  var base = base.toUpperCase();
  var dir = dir.toUpperCase();

  var s = SpreadsheetApp;
  var ss = s.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var saved = ss.getSheetByName('Signals');
  var lastRow = saved.getLastRow();
  var data = saved.getRange(2, 1, lastRow, 12).getValues();

  if (drawmin > 0) {    
   var drawmin = drawmin/100
  }
  if (drawmax > 0) {  
   var drawmax = drawmax/100
  }
  if (askmin > 0) {
   var askmin = askmin/100
  }
  if (askmax > 0) {
   var askmax = askmax/100
  }
  if (excessmin > 0) {
   var excessmin = excessmin/100
  }
  if (excessmax > 0) {
    var excessmax = excessmax/100
  }

  var array = []
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

    var exchange = data[i][0];
    var baseC = data[i][1];
    var direction = data[i][2];
    var coin = data[i][3];
    var duration = data[i][4];
    var drawdown = data[i][5];
    var askSpread = data[i][6];
    var excess = data[i][7];

    if(exch == exchange && base == baseC && dir == direction && duration >= durmin && duration <= durmax && drawdown <= drawmin && drawdown >= drawmax && askSpread >= askmin && askSpread <= askmax && excess >= excessmin && excess <= excessmax) {
      Logger.log('1')  
      array.push(
          {
            "exchange": exchange,
            "base": baseC,
            "direction": direction,
            "coin": coin,
            "duration": Number(duration.toPrecision(2)),
            "draw_down": Number((drawdown*100).toPrecision(2)),
            "ask_highest_spread": Number((askSpread*100).toPrecision(2)),
            "excess_above_target": Number((excess*100).toPrecision(2))

          }
        )
    } else if(exch == exchange && base == baseC && dir == direction && duration >= durmin && duration <= durmax && drawdown <= drawmin && drawdown >= drawmax && askSpread >= askmin && askSpread <= askmax && excess >= excessmin && excess <= excessmax) {
      Logger.log('2')   
      array.push(
          {
            "exchange": exchange,
            "base": baseC,
            "direction": direction,
            "coin": coin,
            "duration": Number(duration.toPrecision(2)),
            "draw_down": Number((drawdown*100).toPrecision(2)),
            "ask_highest_spread": Number((askSpread*100).toPrecision(2)),
            "excess_above_target": Number((excess*100).toPrecision(2))
          }
        )
    } else if(exch == exchange && base == baseC && dir == direction && duration >= durmin && duration <= durmax && drawdown <= drawmin && drawdown >= drawmax && askSpread >= askmin && askSpread <= askmax && excess >= excessmin) {
      Logger.log('3')  
      array.push(
          {
            "exchange": exchange,
            "base": baseC,
            "direction": direction,
            "coin": coin,
            "duration": Number(duration.toPrecision(2)),
            "draw_down": Number((drawdown*100).toPrecision(2)),
            "ask_highest_spread": Number((askSpread*100).toPrecision(2)),
            "excess_above_target": Number((excess*100).toPrecision(2))
          }
        )
    } else if(exch == exchange && base == baseC && dir == direction && duration >= durmin && duration <= durmax && drawdown <= drawmin && drawdown >= drawmax && askSpread >= askmin && askSpread <= askmax) {
      Logger.log('4')  
      array.push(
          {
            "exchange": exchange,
            "base": baseC,
            "direction": direction,
            "coin": coin,
            "duration": Number(duration.toPrecision(2)),
            "draw_down": Number((drawdown*100).toPrecision(2)),
            "ask_highest_spread": Number((askSpread*100).toPrecision(2)),
            "excess_above_target": Number((excess*100).toPrecision(2))
          }
        )
    } else if(exch == exchange && base == baseC && dir == direction && duration >= durmin && duration <= durmax && drawdown <= drawmin && drawdown >= drawmax && askSpread >= askmin) {
      Logger.log('5')   
      array.push(
          {
            "exchange": exchange,
            "base": baseC,
            "direction": direction,
            "coin": coin,
            "duration": Number(duration.toPrecision(2)),
            "draw_down": Number((drawdown*100).toPrecision(2)),
            "ask_highest_spread": Number((askSpread*100).toPrecision(2)),
            "excess_above_target": Number((excess*100).toPrecision(2))
          }
        )
    } else if(exch == exchange && base == baseC && dir == direction && duration >= durmin && duration <= durmax && drawdown >= drawmax && askSpread >= askmin) {
      Logger.log('6')    
      array.push(
          {
            "exchange": exchange,
            "base": baseC,
            "direction": direction,
            "coin": coin,
            "duration": Number(duration.toPrecision(2)),
            "draw_down": Number((drawdown*100).toPrecision(2)),
            "ask_highest_spread": Number((askSpread*100).toPrecision(2)),
            "excess_above_target": Number((excess*100).toPrecision(2))
          }
        )
    } else if (exch == exchange && base == baseC && dir == direction && duration <= durmax && drawdown >= drawmax && askSpread >= askmin) {
      Logger.log('7')  
      array.push(
          {
            "exchange": exchange,
            "base": baseC,
            "direction": direction,
            "coin": coin,
            "duration": Number(duration.toPrecision(2)),
            "draw_down": Number((drawdown*100).toPrecision(2)),
            "ask_highest_spread": Number((askSpread*100).toPrecision(2)),
            "excess_above_target": Number((excess*100).toPrecision(2))
          }
        )

    }
  }
  return array
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry for my poor English skill. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide a sample input and output values? I think that the visual information using sample values will help users think of about your issue. And can I ask you about the relationship between ``this method requires me to key in all 250+ combinations of params based on if statements.`` and your script?

Comment: I have edited the question now to show my full current script. The relation I am talking about with 250+ is in the if statements `if(exch == exchange && base == baseC && dir == direction && duration >= durmin && duration <= durmax && drawdown <= drawmin && drawdown >= drawmax && askSpread >= askmin && askSpread <= askmax && excess >= excessmin && excess <= excessmax)` and the combinations of all parameters that will need to be changed if done manually.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now I noticed that several answers have already been posted. I think that they will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with 2D arrays, it can be helpful for you to convert from the index notation to an annotated object, flattening the object and replacing index access with property access:

```
const relationship = {
  // array index: property name
  0: "exchange",
  ...
};
var annotated = data.map(function (row) {
  // row is an array, lets make it an object:
  return row.reduce(function (obj, value, idx) {
    var prop = relationship[idx];
    obj[prop] = value;
    return obj;
  }, {});
});
// `annotated` is now an array of objects with usefully named properties instead of an array of arrays of values
```

The next step is to start filtering. You seem to have two kinds of tests - equality and "in range," and these are probably most easily handled separately.  Assuming you have created an object that has the keys specified by the user (rather than using a ton of separate variables, we use one object with those variables as properties), we can simplify the equality checks:

```
const requestedInfo = {
  "exchange": exchange,
  "base": base,
  "direction": direction,
  ...
};

// some request parameters denote "ranges," not equality; they don't go in here.
const requiredEqualKeys = ["exchange", "base", ... ];
var meetsEqualityCriteria = annotated.filter(function (obj) {
  return requiredEqualKeys.every(function (key) { return requestedInfo[key] === undefined || obj[key] === requestedInfo[key]; });
});
```

The `Array#every` method will only return `true` (thus telling `Array#filter` to keep that object) if the function called for each value in that array (`requiredEqualKeys`) returns true. Our equality check first determines if that parameter was even given as input, and only if it was is the requested value required to be the same as that in the object being filtered (e.g. if the request didn't include a `base`, no exclusion on `base` would be done). It's possible you should add a check for the requested property being `null`; I leave that to the reader. (If you didn't annotate your `data`, you would be accessing these values by array index only, and it's really easy to get that wrong when your data changes format / order!)

Once you've reduced the objects to only those that satisfy the requested equality, you can apply additional tests, like whether a property is within a requested range. When you defined `requestedInfo`, for range values you should create a nested object, e.g.

```
const requestedInfo = {
  ...
  "ask": {
    "min": askMin, // can set defaults per @TheMaster's answer here too
    "max": askMax
  },
  ...
}
```

This allows you to test the property and whether your object's value is in range:

```
const rangeKeys = [ "ask", "duration", ... ];
var meetsEQandRangeCriteria = meetsEqualityCriteria.filter(function (obj) {
  return rangeKeys.every(function (prop) {
    var rqProp = requestedInfo[prop];
    if (rqProp === undefined)
      return true; // property not present in request
    if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(prop) || obj[prop] < rqProp.min || obj[prop] > rqProp.max)
      return false; // not present in object but was requested, or out-of-range 
    else
      return true;
  });
});
```

Now you are left with an array of objects that met all equality and range-based criteria you requested. You can return it as-is, or per your code in post, return a formatted equivalent:

```
return meetsEQandRangeCriteria.map(function (obj) {
  return {
    "base": obj.base,
    ...
    "excess_above_target": Number((obj.excess * 100).toPrecision(2))
  };
});
```

References:

- [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

Comment: Thank you for going in depth on your answer. I'm attempting to make changes and I've gotten the equality section functioning. However, I'm running into issues of the range section returning nothing back, and I'm trying to figure out why that could be. Just to double check, I'm using the keys (in string format) from my `requestedInfo` object correct?

Comment: @phil the range test section is assuming that `prop` is single-valued in each object constructed from your `data`, e.g. `{"ask": 40}`, while the value of that same property in `requestedInfo` is an object, e.g. `{ "ask": {"min": 20, "max": 41} }`. This may be helpful: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting#using_the_debugger_and_breakpoints

Comment: Excellent, very helpful. I've never used any of those options decribed in your answer before, so thank you.

Answer (score 2):

When parsing the query string, set default values for optional parameters[<sup>1</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators), if not present.

#### Snippet:

```
function doGet(f){
  const e = f.parameter;
  const durmin = e.durmin || -Infinity;
  const durmax = e.durmax || Infinity;
```

Comment: This is helpful, I wasn't aware you could do this.

Comment: @Phil If that solves the issue, you can accept the answer.